# Output file does not appear from StreamWriter

Tags: powershell

I am trying to implement the code at this highly rated page [https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gbordier/2009/05/05/powershell-and-writing-files-how-fast-can-you-write-to-a-file/ using](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gbordier/2009/05/05/powershell-and-writing-files-how-fast-can-you-write-to-a-file/%20using) "Method 4."

When I run the code below, it does appear to take a few seconds, but no t.txt file appears to be created. What am I missing?

```
PS L:\users\lit\t> Get-Content .\ttt.ps1
$s = "some text"

$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "t.txt"
1..10000 | % {
      $stream.WriteLine($s)
}
$stream.close()
PS L:\users\lit\t> $PSVersionTable["PSVersion"]

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10586  117
```

Comment: The file most likely just isn't created where you expect it. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41577673/1630171) to a somewhat similar question. PowerShell and .Net don't necessarily use the same working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @Ansgar Wiechers. The only way I could place the file into the correct directory was to produce a full path from a root. Since I wanted to put it into the current directory, `(Get-Location).Path` provided the directory path to which I appended the file name.

Without specifying the full path, `System.IO.StreamWriter` wanted to put the file into my home directory.

```
PS C:\Users\lit\t\booo> Get-Content .\ttt.ps1
[cmdletbinding()]
Param()

$FullPath = Join-Path (Get-Location).Path "t.txt"
Write-Verbose $FullPath

$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $FullPath
Write-Verbose $stream.BaseStream.Name

1..10 | % { $stream.WriteLine($_) }

$stream.close()
PS C:\Users\lit\t\booo> .\ttt.ps1 -Verbose
VERBOSE: C:\Users\lit\t\booo\t.txt
VERBOSE: C:\Users\lit\t\booo\t.txt
PS C:\Users\lit\t\booo> Get-ChildItem

        Directory: C:\Users\lit\t\booo

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/11/2017   5:22 PM             31 t.txt
-a----        1/11/2017   5:21 PM            251 ttt.ps1
```